# Supermicro X10 motherboard with discrete GPU and onboard IPMI GPU and access via KVM

Tags: ipmi, keyboard-video-mouse, graphics-processing-unit

Is it possible to have both GPUs running and connected to displays at the same time (with mirrored displays for example) but then also connect via the IPMI iKVM to the built in GPU?

I will need access to a remote workstation with an X10 class supermicro motherboard (not yet bought) via KVM that has a discrete GPU installed and used but I'm not sure whether iKVM will work in this instance.  As said, both outputs will be connected to a displays and enabled so I'm assuming that this should be ok as long as the BIOS supports it?

Is anyone able to confirm that this approach can work before I spend the money?

Very much appreciate any responses.

Cheers,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the Java iKVM console will show graphics *only* from the built-in GPU, and *not* from any add-in graphics cards you may install.

Keep in mind that its purpose is for remote management of the system, especially in the pre-boot environment or when the operating system fails to boot properly, *not* for normal day-to-day usage. Use whatever facilities your operating system provides instead, if you need remote access to the screen during normal operation.

Comment: Thank you Michael, I understand that it would only show the built in GPU display, and this is what I wanted.  Its not to run the system, that is done through the discrete card but to ensure that any maintenance can be achieved on the system remotely without the user being present if the system has failed; Generally it would be an RDC sort of connection... iKVM is just useful if it bluescreens and therefore RDC doesn't work!